# Spring-Security não funciona com página de login customizada

Tags: spring-security

Estou iniciando no Spring Security (Na verdade sou novo no Spring em geral kkk) e estou com um problema a alguns dias já.
Primeiramente eu fiz teste com a tela de login padrão do Spring Security, coloque usuário "user" e a senha que o Spring Security fornece, este teste deu ok, consegui sucesso no login.
mas ao tentar com minha própria página de login, não estou conseguindo autenticar, clico no botão, a tela dá uma leve carregada e não ocorre nada.

Abaixo deixarei meu código, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

**Login.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
.bd-placeholder-img {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    text-anchor: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

@media ( min-width : 768px) {
    .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
    }
}
</style>
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST" th:action="@{/login}">
        <fieldset>
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">    
                    Usuario ou Senha invalidos.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success"> 
                    Você foi desconectado.
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(mensagem)}">
                <span th:text="${mensagem}">Mensagem vem do Controller</span>
            </div>
            <img class="mb-4" src="/images/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72"
                height="72">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Entrar</h1>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" id="username " class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus name="username" th:value="${usuario?.getUsuario()}"/>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required name="password" th:value="${usuario?.getSenha()}"/>
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                <a href="/RecupSenha.html">Esqueceu a Senha?</a>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2020</p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**LoginController**

```
package com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.repository.Usuarios;
import com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.service.UsuarioServices;

@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private Usuarios usuarios;
    
    @Autowired
    UsuarioServices segurancaServices;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("Login");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
package com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.security.config;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll() //autoriza pastas css, js, images e seus respectivos arquivos
            .antMatchers("/", "home").permitAll()   //autoriza pagina home
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login-error")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

}
```

Se eu comentar a linha ".loginPage("/login")" ao executar o projeto utilizo a pagina login padrão do Spring-Security, nela consigo autenticar usuário user normalmente, mas não é a página padrão que eu desejo utilizar.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.SystemsSolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebControl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>WebControl</name>
    <description>Sistema de Gestão</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Acho que documentei o suficiente, caso precise de mais informações me avise. Grato!

Comment: Olá Rafael, não é necessário adicionar o sufixo "resolvido" às perguntas que têm resposta aceita. O próprio sistema já faz essa identificação quando uma resposta da pergunta é aceita. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido com ajuda da documentação abaixo
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.19.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#overriding-the-default-configure-httpsecurity-method

A pergunta acima já foi editada com a solução, o código está funcionando. Espero que sirva de exemplo para muitos :)